# Laravel Voyager Route Restriction

Tags: laravel, vue.js, voyager

How to do this:
1. Access route only when user is login.
2. Redirect to voyager login when accessing the restricted page.

```
Route::get('/call_sheet', 'CallSheetsController@index');
```

the route returns a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Voyager middleware`.

```
Route::get('/call_sheet', 'CallSheetsController@index')->middleware('admin.user');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can i redirect it to 'test.local/admin/login of Voyager .. not to test.local/login' which is generated by auth. ?

Comment: hmm .. i don't  think so sir .. i will not use the prefix admin.. my url is test.local/call_sheet ..

Comment: You are misunderstood whole point. middleware('admin.user') is redirecting directly admin/login. my first answer is working perfectly :)

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer for me too and should be accepted.